# How can I find hotel properties to buy other than using Google?

Tags: investing, rental-property

I am looking to invest in hotel properties in the USA, where do I start? I have spent two hours on google and have come up with next to little.

Comment: You mean, besides talking to a commercial real estate agent?

Comment: Investing $1000.00 or $20,000,000.00?  That will make a difference in approach...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to invest in hotel rooms in the U.S. is to invest in a [Real Estate Investment Trust](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/reit.asp), or REIT.  REITs are securities that invest in real estate and trade like a stock.  There are different REITs that invest in different things: some own office buildings, some residential rentals, some hold mortgages, and some are diversified in lots of different types of real estate.  There are also REITs that are exclusively invested in hotels.

REITs are required to pay out at least 90% of their profits as dividends, and there are tax advantages to investing in REITs.

You can search for a REIT on [REIT.com's Searchable Directory](https://www.reit.com/investing/investor-research/reit-directories/searchable-directory).  You can select a type (Lodging/Resorts), a stock exchange (NYSE), investment sector (equity), and a listing status (public), and you'll see lots of investments for you to consider.